# Numerical and computational approaches to limit cycle theory

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, na.numerical-analysis, big-list, limit-cycles, computation

I am searching for a  big list  of  papers  or  researches  devoted to limit  cycles of  planar polynomial vector  fields based  on  a computational  and  numerical  approach.

I  would  like to ask moderators  to  consider this  question as  a  wiki  question.

Comment: Is this a "Hilbert's 16th Problem" question?

Comment: @MichaelLee  Yes, Limit cycles are the main object of the second part of the  Hilbert 16th problem.

Comment: Check out the work of Jaume Llibre.